How to add multiple secrets from azure devops library to azure key vault using terraform
I want to have a yaml pipeline that pulls all my secrets out of an azure devops library and pushes them into key vault as secrets using terraform.
I'm already able to pull values out of a library and access them inside terraform as environment variable by doing what is below for example...
tenantId=$(tf-sp-tenant-id)
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TF_VAR_tenant_id]$tenantId"   


I want to do something like this but not sure how to name them all in devops library so they all map automatically to the secrets variable below.. and then how to pass them all into a module that has map(string) as a input variable?
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "example" {
  for_each            = var.secrets
  name                = each.key
  value               = each.value
  key_vault_id        = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
}

variable "tenant_id" {
  description = "The Tenant ID for the Azure Key Vault"
}

variable "secrets" {
  type        = map(string)
  description = "A map of secrets to store in the Azure Key Vault"
}



I want to do something like this but not sure how to name them all in devops library so they all map automatically to the secrets variable below.. and then how to pass them all into a module that has map(string) as a input variable?

I'm afraid it's not supported.
The secret variables from Key vault will NOT be mapped as environment variables, you have to explicitly invoke it, or create a new variable to map the value as you did in echo "##vso[task.setvariable... command.  The variable secrets in terraform is a map of strings,  it accepts environment value like TF_VAR_secrets={"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}, you cannot automatically have the value from devops secret variables in environment.
